# Html Sort table with a priority not working

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-table

I am writing this code for a SharePoint 2010.

now It can sort the table alphabetically but I need it to be different. and sadly it isn't changing the variables a and b to get it to change.  I want to pick up the priority and move it by the next priority on the list. it isn't working for some odd reason cannot figure out what I am doing.
I am trying to alert me the changes to A and B and its coming up as undefined...

```js
function sortStatusTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, a, b, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount =  0;
  table = document.getElementById("claimsTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
       dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
  //start by saying: no switching is done:
  switching = false;
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
  /*Loop through all table rows (except the
  first, which contains table headers):*/
  for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
    //start by saying there should be no switching:
    shouldSwitch = false;
    /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
    one from current row and one from the next:*/
    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
    y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];


    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == "Critical"){
    a = "a";
   }

    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() =="High"){
    a = "b";
   }

    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() =="Medium"){
    a = "c";
   }

    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() =="Low"){
    a = "d";
   }

   if (y.innerHTML.toLowerCase() =="Critical"){
    b = "a";
   }

    if (y.innerHTML.toLowerCase() =="High"){
    b = "b";
   }

    if (y.innerHTML.toLowerCase() =="Medium"){
    b = "c";
   }

    if (y.innerHTML.toLowerCase() =="Low"){
    b = "d";
   }

   console(a);
   console(b)
    /*check if the two rows should switch place,
    based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
   if (dir == "asc") {
      if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
        shouldSwitch= true;
        break;
      }
    } else if (dir == "desc") {
      if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
        shouldSwitch= true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (shouldSwitch) {
    /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
    and mark that a switch has been done:*/
    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
    switching = true;
    //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
    switchcount ++;      
  } else {
    /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
    set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
    if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
      dir = "desc";
      switching = true;
    }
  }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the mistake I made was when I made the if statements I never accounted for the fact that the names are all lowercased. "Medium" instead of "medium".

```
if (y.innerHTML.toLowerCase() =="medium"){
    var b = "c";
 }
```

then I did this part

```
if (dir == "asc") {
    if (a > b) {
      //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
  } else if (dir == "desc") {
    if (a < b) {
      //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
  }
```